# Selenium: Getting 404 error with ChomeDriver browser but not Chrome

Tags: selenium, browser, http-status-code-404, selenium-chromedriver

I have a weird problem going on with a Selenium test.  I have an internal company website that I'm writing a Selenium test for and am getting a 404 error ONLY with the browser instance that Selenium opens up.  It doesn't matter if its Chrome or Firefox, I still get the 404.

To prove its only with the browser instance that Selenium opens I have run my test in debug mode, paused it when the browser launches and then manually executed the test case within that browser instance and I always get a 404.

Now, if I open a normal Chrome or Firefox browser instance outside of Selenium I can manually execute the test case just fine.

Manual execution of the test case in Chrome Incognito also works.

What am I missing here?

Apparently something else needs to be loaded with in the browser but I have no idea what.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Update the question with the relevant _HTML_ for a proper analysis

Comment: you are getting 404 only for some page or for the whole site? check network options for proxy, maybe you have to add it to chrome/firefox arguments.

Comment: I'm getting the error on log in.  When I hit the site the log on page loads, but then once I click submit after entering the user id / password I get the 404.

Comment: Selenium by default uses a temporary browser profile. You maybe have a security token in your existing browser profile.

Answer (score 0):

I found that we had a redirect problem on our server, however it still doesn't make sense as to why it failed in WebDriver but not in a normal browser.  Either way, its resolved.